# How to delay simulated touch events?

Tags: android

I am making a musical app for Android, in which I detect ontouch events done by the user, making the pressed keys sound, and also get their colour changed. I would like to make simulated events in order to show the notes of a song.

The problem I am facing is that there's no delay between each touch event, or at least I don't know how to do it properly. You can hear the sound of both notes, but you can't see their colour change.

How should it be done?

This is what I've tested in order to get 2 keys pressed. I tried it also by making an `ACTION_UP` between, but it didn't work.

```
//First key pressed
piano.dispatchTouchEvent(pulse.obtain(SystemClock.upTimeMillis(),SystemClock.upTimeMillis() + 1000, pulse.ACTION_DOWN,0,0,8)

//Second key pressed
piano.dispatchTouchEvent(pulse.obtain(SystemClock.upTimeMillis(),SystemClock.upTimeMillis() + 1000, pulse.ACTION_DOWN,80,0,8)
```

I haven't considered the posibility of touching 2 notes at the same time, only one per touch event.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Press {
  static final long PRESS_DELAY = 150;

  private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

  private final View view;

  Press(View view) {
    this.view = view;
  }

  void press() {
    if (view.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
      return;
    }
    view.setPressed(true);
    view.invalidate();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        view.setPressed(false);
        view.invalidate();
      }
    }, PRESS_DELAY);
  }
}
```

then,

```
new Press(myButton).press();
```